# Solana candy machine upload assets Error: memory allocation failed, out of memory

Tags: solana, metaplex, candy-machine

I was trying to upload testing content by

```
ts-node src/candy-machine-cli.ts upload assets --env devnet --keypair "~\.config\solana\devnet.json" -n 10
```

And ran into error below

> Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 1: Program
> failed to complete
> Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]
> Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success
> Program cndyAnrLdpjq1Ssp1z8xxDsB8dxe7u4HL5Nxi2K5WXZ invoke [1]
> Program log: Error: memory allocation failed, out of memory
> Program cndyAnrLdpjq1Ssp1z8xxDsB8dxe7u4HL5Nxi2K5WXZ consumed 200000 of 200000 compute units
> Program failed to complete: BPF program panicked
> Program cndyAnrLdpjq1Ssp1z8xxDsB8dxe7u4HL5Nxi2K5WXZ failed: Program failed to complete

I think the message may be misleading since I'm processing only 10 images. But not sure what exactly went wrong.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar error in Candy Machine v2.
Turns out one of my token names was longer than 32 characters.
It's completely undocumented, but check the names of your tokens.

0.json

```
{
  "name": "Apparently this name was too long",
  "symbol": "",
  "image": "0.png",
  "properties": {
    "files": [
      {
        "uri": "0.png",
        "type": "image/png"
      }
    ],
    "creators": [
      {
        "address": "3PH55LMruoQnMmEXLgofGDk3XE2ktDtCZso7K4EeYdQZ",
        "share": 50
      },
      {
        "address": "2iZ2Wpp96P5ncpBcGnrvRDFnts9fgBBTYHDbZgb5SDYa",
        "share": 50
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not documented but according to Metaplex's code, the name length limit is 32

All the size limits for candy machine metadata can be found here (defined [here](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex/blob/8555003e3ffe6adc5f7390e02ee9779ad293198b/js/packages/cli/src/helpers/constants.ts#L10)).

Important values people commonly have errors with are:

```
MAX_NAME_LENGTH = 32;
MAX_SYMBOL_LENGTH = 10;
MAX_URI_LENGTH = 200;
```

so definitely start with checking the name length and symbol length in your metadata. The verify_metadata cmd in metaplex cli will also help to check for this before you upload.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer for my case on [issue-exploer of metaplex](https://issueexplorer.com/issue/metaplex-foundation/metaplex/479)

Although don't really get why; the issue can be prevented by keeping `"symbol": ""`.

*This json property locates in each asset.json and is sourced from `traits-configuration.json`